# spaCy blank NER model underfitting even when trained on a large dataset

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to create a custom NER model for identifying cybersecurity related entities (27 of them). I decided to go with a blank model because I think I have a large enough (not sure about this) training dataset (~11k sentences extracted from Wikipedia).

To create the training data required by spaCy, I used the *PhraseMatcher* utility. The idea is to match certain predefined words/phrases related to the entities I want to identify as illustrated below:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("en")

import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

from collections import defaultdict
```

### Specify Matcher Labels

```
users_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("user", "human", "person", "people", "end user")]
devices_pattern =  [nlp(text) for text in ("device", "peripheral", "appliance", "component", "accesory", "equipment", "machine")]
accounts_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("account", "user account", "username", "user name", "loginname", "login name", "screenname", "screen name", "account name")]
identifiers_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("attribute", "id", "ID", "code", "ID code")]
authentication_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("authentication", "authenticity", "certification", "verification", "attestation", "authenticator", "authenticators")]
time_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("time", "date", "moment", "present", "pace", "moment")]
unauthorized_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("unauthorized", "illegal", "illegitimate", "pirated", "unapproved", "unjustified", "unofficial")]
disclosure_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("disclosure", "acknowledgment", "admission", "exposure", "advertisement", "divulgation")]
network_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("network", "net", "networking", "internet", "Internet")]
wireless_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("wireless", "wifi", "Wi-Fi", "wireless networking")]
password_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("password", "passwords", "passcode", "passphrase")]
configuration_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("configuration", "composition")]
signatures_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("signature", "signatures", "digital signature", "electronic signature")]
certificates_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("certificate", "digital certificates", "authorization certificate", "public key certificates", "PKI", "X509", "X.509")]
revocation_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("revocation", "annulment", "cancellation")]
keys_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("key", "keys")]
algorithms_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("algorithm", "algorithms", "formula", "program")]
standard_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("standard", "standards", "specification", "specifications", "norm", "rule", "rules", "RFC")]
invalid_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("invalid", "false", "unreasonable", "inoperative")]
access_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("access", "connection", "entry", "entrance")]
blocking_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("blocking", "block", "blacklist", "blocklist", "close", "cut off", "deter", "prevent", "stop")]
notification_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("notification", "notifications", "notice", "warning")]
messages_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("message", "messages", "note", "news")]
untrusted_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("untrusted", "malicious", "unsafe")]
security_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("security", "secure", "securely", "protect", "defend", "guard")]
symmetric_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("symmetric", "symmetric crypto")]
asymmetric_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("asymmetric", "asymmetric crypto")]

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("USER", None, *users_pattern)
matcher.add("DEVICE", None, *devices_pattern)
matcher.add("ACCOUNT", None, *accounts_pattern)
matcher.add("IDENTIFIER", None, *identifiers_pattern)
matcher.add("AUTHENTICATION", None, *authentication_pattern)
matcher.add("TIME", None, *time_pattern)
matcher.add("UNAUTHORIZED", None, *unauthorized_pattern)
matcher.add("DISCLOSURE", None, *disclosure_pattern)
matcher.add("NETWORK", None, *network_pattern)
matcher.add("WIRELESS", None, *wireless_pattern)
matcher.add("PASSWORD", None, *password_pattern)
matcher.add("CONFIGURATION", None, *configuration_pattern)
matcher.add("SIGNATURE", None, *signatures_pattern)
matcher.add("CERTIFICATE", None, *certificates_pattern)
matcher.add("REVOCATION", None, *revocation_pattern)
matcher.add("KEY", None, *keys_pattern)
matcher.add("ALGORITHM", None, *algorithms_pattern)
matcher.add("STANDARD", None, *standard_pattern)
matcher.add("INVALID", None, *invalid_pattern)
matcher.add("ACCESS", None, *access_pattern)
matcher.add("BLOCKING", None, *blocking_pattern)
matcher.add("NOTIFICATION", None, *notification_pattern)
matcher.add("MESSAGE", None, *messages_pattern)
matcher.add("UNTRUSTED", None, *untrusted_pattern)
matcher.add("SECURITY", None, *security_pattern)
matcher.add("SYMMETRIC", None, *symmetric_pattern)
matcher.add("ASYMMETRIC", None, *asymmetric_pattern)
```

### Prepare Training Data

```
def offsetter(lbl, doc, matchitem):
    """
    Convert PhaseMatcher result to the format required in training (start, end, label)
    """
    o_one = len(str(doc[0:matchitem[1]]))
    subdoc = doc[matchitem[1]:matchitem[2]]
    o_two = o_one + len(str(subdoc))
    return (o_one, o_two, lbl)


to_train_ents = []
count_dic = defaultdict(int)

# Load the original sentences
df = pd.read_csv("sentences.csv", index_col=False)
phrases = df["sentence"].values

for line in tqdm(phrases):

    nlp_line = nlp(line)
    matches = matcher(nlp_line)
    
    if matches:
        
        for match in matches:

            match_id = match[0]
            start = match[1]
            end = match[2]

            label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
            span = nlp_line[start:end]  # get the matched slice of the doc

            count_dic[label] += 1

            res = [offsetter(label, nlp_line, match)]
            to_train_ents.append((line, dict(entities=res)))
           
count_dic = dict(count_dic)
        
TRAIN_DATA =  to_train_ents
```

After executing the above code, I obtained the training data in the format required by spaCy. These sentences contain the entities I am interested which are distributed as shown below:

```
print(sorted(count_dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True), len(count_dic))
sum(count_dic.values())


[('NETWORK', 1962), ('TIME', 1489), ('USER', 1206), ('SECURITY', 981), ('DEVICE', 884), ('STANDARD', 796), ('ACCESS', 652), ('ALGORITHM', 651), ('MESSAGE', 605), ('KEY', 423), ('IDENTIFIER', 389), ('BLOCKING', 354), ('AUTHENTICATION', 141), ('WIRELESS', 109), ('UNAUTHORIZED', 99), ('CONFIGURATION', 89), ('ACCOUNT', 86), ('UNTRUSTED', 77), ('PASSWORD', 62), ('DISCLOSURE', 58), ('NOTIFICATION', 55), ('INVALID', 44), ('SIGNATURE', 41), ('SYMMETRIC', 23), ('ASYMMETRIC', 11), ('CERTIFICATE', 10), ('REVOCATION', 9)] 27
11306
```

I then used the *standard* training procedure to train a blank NER model in spaCy illustrated below.

### Training the Blank model

```
# define variables
model = None  
n_iter = 100

if model is not None:
    nlp_new = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
else:
    nlp_new = spacy.blank("en")  # create blank Language class
    print("Created blank 'en' model")

# Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline
# nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
if "ner" not in nlp_new.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp_new.create_pipe("ner")
    nlp_new.add_pipe(ner)
# otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
else:
    ner = nlp_new.get_pipe("ner")


# add labels
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for ent in annotations.get("entities"):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])
            
# get names of other pipes to disable them during training
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp_new.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]

with nlp_new.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp_new.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp_new.resume_training()
    
    
    # Set this based on this resource: spacy compounding batch size
    sizes = compounding(1, 16, 1.001)
    
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
    for itn in tqdm(range(n_iter)):
        losses = {}
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp_new.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2, losses=losses)
        print("Losses", losses)
```

The final loss after this is about 500.

Finally, I tested how the new model performed using the training data. I would expect to recover as much as entities as specified originally in the training dataset. However, after running the below code I only get about ~600 instances out of ~11k in total.

### Test Trained Model

```
count_dic = defaultdict(int)

for text, _ in TRAIN_DATA:
    
    doc = nlp_new(text)
    
    for ent in doc.ents:
        count_dic[ent.label_] += 1
        
print(sorted(count_dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True), len(count_dic))
sum(count_dic.values())

[('TIME', 369), ('NETWORK', 47), ('IDENTIFIER', 41), ('BLOCKING', 28), ('USER', 22), ('STANDARD', 22), ('SECURITY', 15), ('MESSAGE', 15), ('ACCESS', 7), ('CONFIGURATION', 7), ('DEVICE', 7), ('KEY', 4), ('ALGORITHM', 3), ('SYMMETRIC', 2), ('UNAUTHORIZED', 2), ('SIGNATURE', 2), ('WIRELESS', 1), ('DISCLOSURE', 1), ('INVALID', 1), ('PASSWORD', 1), ('NOTIFICATION', 1)] 21
598
```

I wonder why this procedure is producing a model with such underfitting behavior. I am aware of the comments in these posts: [NER training using Spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962469/ner-training-using-spacy) and [SPACY custom NER is not returning any entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008854/spacy-custom-ner-is-not-returning-any-entity) but they do not address my issue.

I hope you can provide any feedback about what I have done and how I can improve detection of entities in the training set. I thought that 11k sentences would be enough unless I am doing something wrong. I am using Python 3.6.9 and spaCy 2.2.4.

Thank you so much for your help.

### Update

I decided to train the model including both positive and negative samples. Now the training data has over 40k sentences. This change however, does dot improve the classification result in the training set. Any other suggestions?

### Training dataset

The complete training dataset can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZNwVrW4kyXYSEn4-tmZqFfAqRaVM9b56/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of input data?

Comment: Just added the input data @raqib

Comment: I went through the code. I have a few questions for you before I venture deeper into this, What is your purpose for training a model? Do you have the predefined number of phrases i.e. the 27 categories, that you are looking for, or are you looking to generalize into cyber security terms you havn't seen before? If so, how do you intend on categorizing them?

Comment: My purpose is to train a NER model for identifying 27 predefined cybersecurity categories. I am not planning in generalizing to terms that I have not seen before. Thanks @raqib

Answer (score 1):

Underfitting may be due the fact that spacy blank models are too small to perform well in your situation. In my experience spacy blank models are about 5Mb which is small (especially if we compare it with the size of spacy pretrained models that can be around 500 Mb).

Indeed, you have 27 different labels and a lot of data.

I don't know if it is possible to create bigger spacy models from scratch. Answers welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that training a spaCy model is the right choice in your case. The goal of training a spaCy model would be to generalize. In your case, you are only interested in the 27 predefined categories, using a rule based approach would be the right choice here in my opinion.

There are two ways I can think of to approach this problem:

1. Regex (adds no external dependency of using and downloading spaCy)
2. Rule Based Matching capabilities of spaCy (Token Matcher, Phrase Matcher or Entity Ruler)

**Note:**

You have already solved the problem using PhraseMatcher above.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

import pandas as pd


nlp = spacy.load("en")

users_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("user", "human", "person", "people", "end user")]
devices_pattern =  [nlp(text) for text in ("device", "peripheral", "appliance", "component", "accesory", "equipment", "machine")]
accounts_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("account", "user account", "username", "user name", "loginname", "login name", "screenname", "screen name", "account name")]
identifiers_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("attribute", "id", "ID", "code", "ID code")]
authentication_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("authentication", "authenticity", "certification", "verification", "attestation", "authenticator", "authenticators")]
time_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("time", "date", "moment", "present", "pace", "moment")]
unauthorized_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("unauthorized", "illegal", "illegitimate", "pirated", "unapproved", "unjustified", "unofficial")]
disclosure_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("disclosure", "acknowledgment", "admission", "exposure", "advertisement", "divulgation")]
network_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("network", "net", "networking", "internet", "Internet")]
wireless_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("wireless", "wifi", "Wi-Fi", "wireless networking")]
password_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("password", "passwords", "passcode", "passphrase")]
configuration_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("configuration", "composition")]
signatures_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("signature", "signatures", "digital signature", "electronic signature")]
certificates_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("certificate", "digital certificates", "authorization certificate", "public key certificates", "PKI", "X509", "X.509")]
revocation_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("revocation", "annulment", "cancellation")]
keys_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("key", "keys")]
algorithms_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("algorithm", "algorithms", "formula", "program")]
standard_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("standard", "standards", "specification", "specifications", "norm", "rule", "rules", "RFC")]
invalid_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("invalid", "false", "unreasonable", "inoperative")]
access_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("access", "connection", "entry", "entrance")]
blocking_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("blocking", "block", "blacklist", "blocklist", "close", "cut off", "deter", "prevent", "stop")]
notification_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("notification", "notifications", "notice", "warning")]
messages_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("message", "messages", "note", "news")]
untrusted_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("untrusted", "malicious", "unsafe")]
security_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("security", "secure", "securely", "protect", "defend", "guard")]
symmetric_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("symmetric", "symmetric crypto")]
asymmetric_pattern = [nlp(text) for text in ("asymmetric", "asymmetric crypto")]


matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add("USER", None, *users_pattern)
matcher.add("DEVICE", None, *devices_pattern)
matcher.add("ACCOUNT", None, *accounts_pattern)
matcher.add("IDENTIFIER", None, *identifiers_pattern)
matcher.add("AUTHENTICATION", None, *authentication_pattern)
matcher.add("TIME", None, *time_pattern)
matcher.add("UNAUTHORIZED", None, *unauthorized_pattern)
matcher.add("DISCLOSURE", None, *disclosure_pattern)
matcher.add("NETWORK", None, *network_pattern)
matcher.add("WIRELESS", None, *wireless_pattern)
matcher.add("PASSWORD", None, *password_pattern)
matcher.add("CONFIGURATION", None, *configuration_pattern)
matcher.add("SIGNATURE", None, *signatures_pattern)
matcher.add("CERTIFICATE", None, *certificates_pattern)
matcher.add("REVOCATION", None, *revocation_pattern)
matcher.add("KEY", None, *keys_pattern)
matcher.add("ALGORITHM", None, *algorithms_pattern)
matcher.add("STANDARD", None, *standard_pattern)
matcher.add("INVALID", None, *invalid_pattern)
matcher.add("ACCESS", None, *access_pattern)
matcher.add("BLOCKING", None, *blocking_pattern)
matcher.add("NOTIFICATION", None, *notification_pattern)
matcher.add("MESSAGE", None, *messages_pattern)
matcher.add("UNTRUSTED", None, *untrusted_pattern)
matcher.add("SECURITY", None, *security_pattern)
matcher.add("SYMMETRIC", None, *symmetric_pattern)
matcher.add("ASYMMETRIC", None, *asymmetric_pattern)
```

After adding all the different patterns to the matcher object, the `matcher` object is ready for you to make predictions:

```py
doc = nlp("Attackers can deny service to individual victims, such as by deliberately entering a wrong password enough consecutive times to cause the victims account to be locked, or they may overload the capabilities of a machine or network and block all users at once.")
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        label = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
        span = doc[start:end]
        print(f"label:{label}, start:{start}, end:{end}, text:{span.text}")
```

**Output**

```py
label:PASSWORD, start:15, end:16, text:password
label:ACCOUNT, start:23, end:24, text:account
label:DEVICE, start:36, end:37, text:machine
label:NETWORK, start:38, end:39, text:network
label:BLOCKING, start:40, end:41, text:block
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @raqib. However, independently of the application, I do not understand why training a spaCy NER model with the provided dataset and code still underfit. Any ideas on this are appreciated.

Comment: P.S. It's been a few days, so I might be off a little

`o_two = o_one + len(str(subdoc))` should be `    o_two = o_one + len(str(subdoc)) + 1`. I think that affected the ner labels. 

Can you double check that, and see if anything improves?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @raqib.  I checked what you suggested but doing that change makes the performance deteriorates on the training set.  The distribution is now: `[('USER', 24), ('TIME', 19), ('SECURITY', 12), ('DEVICE', 7), ('IDENTIFIER', 7), ('CONFIGURATION', 5), ('STANDARD', 5), ('ALGORITHM', 4), ('MESSAGE', 4), ('CRYPTO', 3), ('BLOCKING', 3), ('NETWORK', 2), ('SIGNATURE', 2), ('UNAUTHORIZED', 1), ('NOTIFICATION', 1)]`. I was expecting something much better than that given that the loss plateaus around 150 and for the previous method is was around 500.

Comment: I wonder if @syllogism_ has any comments on this. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if @Ines Montani has any comments on this. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if @Sofie VL has any comments on this. Thank you.